# Why is there spacel after floated divs and how can I remove it?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I wanted to use `float: right;`  but it made space after the div and it looks like div has `margin-bottom`, but it actually hasn't.
Why is that?
And how can I remove the space what created by `float: right;`?

```css
.container {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    width: 70%;
}

.line {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.child {
    background-color: coral;
    height: 2em;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="line"><div class="child"></div></div>
            <div class="line"><div class="child"></div></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is a result of the `display: inline-block` property declared on the containing elements (`.line`) of the nested floated elements (`.child`); creating a "*white space*" between sibling elements.

To resolve this, consider declaring a `vertical-align` property on the containing elements (`.line`), as demonstrated below.

```
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top; /* additional */
}
```

*Note:* this property value can be applied to this element due to the *inline* nature of the block element.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.container {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  width: 70%;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top; /* additional */
}

.child {
  background-color: coral;
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `display: flex;`

```css
.container {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  width: 70%;
}

 

.child {
  background-color: coral;
height: 3em;
width: 50%;
display: flex;
margin-left: auto;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```